# How to dynamically select which client ID to use when authenticating to Stripe (OAuth2) using python-social-auth

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, stripe-payments, python-social-auth, stripe-connect

I need my users to have a test mode / live mode switch, exactly like Stripe has on its dashboard. I'm using [`python-social-auth`](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/index.html) to authenticate the user with Stripe, using a custom pipeline step to retrieve the access token and publishable key, and saving it to a field in the user model.

The problem is that I have to define in the settings these two values: `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_KEY` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_SECRET`, but I need something more like `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_TEST_KEY`, `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_TEST_SECRET`, `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_LIVE_KEY` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET`.

Depending on which client id is used when initiating the OAuth flow, that's how Stripe selects which type of API access code to send, if I use my app's test cliend ID, Stripe will only send the test keys for that user. But if I use my production/live client ID, then I will be getting the live access code for that user.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've implemented this in my projects before is to run the Stripe Connect Oauth Process in Live mode. Once you connect to Stripe in live mode and you have a live Access Token and a live Refresh Token for your user, you can use the refresh token to generate a test access token and a test publishable key for your user.

You can see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#post-token for how to convert a live Refresh Token into a test Access Token